# Difficulties coding variables for the choices in a dictionary guessing game

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a guessing game where the user chooses a key within the dictionary and guesses the value of it.
I'm having a hard time trying to code the variables for the choice in order to have to guess the value.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    capitals = {'AL' : 'Montgomery', 'AK' : 'Juneau', 'AZ' : 'Phoenix',
                'AR' : 'Little Rock', 'CA' : 'Sacramento', 'CO' : 'Denver',
                'CT' : 'Hartford', 'FL' : 'Tallahassee', 'GA' : 'Atlanta',
                'HI' : 'Honolulu', 'ID' : 'Boise', 'IL' : 'Springfield',
                'IN' : 'Indianapolis', 'IA' : 'Des Moines', 'KS' : 'Topeka'}
    print("Choose a state from the list", capitals.keys())
    choice = input('Which state would you like to guess? : ')
    choice == capitals.keys()
    guess = input('Guess the capital of the state chosen : ')
    answer = capitals.values()
    if guess == answer:
        print("Yay! You're CORRECT!")
    else:
        print("Sorry, You're INCORRECT!")

main()
```

It seems that my `if` statement isn't being read by the program. How can I fix this?

Comment: Right before your "if guess....." statement, put some print statements eg. print(choice), print (guess), and print(answer). I think your error(s) will become apparent to you. Another option is to start using an IDE such as PyCharm that has step debugging, so you can see your variables change one step at a time. You will want to get yourself in the habit of looking at your variables and soon you will be able to answer these questions without any help : )

Comment: I feel like a curmudgeon saying it, but this feels like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Your semantics are incorrect.  Just before your `if` statement, insert

```
print (guess, answer)
```

This is basic debugging.  You'll see the problem: `answer` is a list of all the capitals; there's no way that raw user input can be equal to an entire list.  You need to compare against only the capital for that one state.

You'll have to make a similar check on `choice`, as you've made teh same mistake there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with the code provided. Here's a working version with inline comments to explain what's going on. While loops allow you to check the input data before moving on.

```
def main():

    capitals = {'AL': 'Montgomery', 'AK': 'Juneau', 'AZ': 'Phoenix',
                'AR': 'Little Rock', 'CA': 'Sacramento', 'CO': 'Denver',
                'CT': 'Hartford', 'FL': 'Tallahassee', 'GA': 'Atlanta',
                'HI': 'Honolulu', 'ID': 'Boise', 'IL': 'Springfield',
                'IN': 'Indianapolis', 'IA': 'Des Moines', 'KS': 'Topeka'}

    # initialize variables used in while loops
    choice = '' 
    guess = ''

    print("Choose a state from the list: {0}".format(' '.join(capitals.keys())))

    # as long as choice is not in the list of capitals, keep asking
    while choice not in capitals.keys():
        choice = input('Which state would you like to guess? : ')

    # get the correct answer for the chosen state
    answer = capitals[choice]

    # as long as the guess doesn't contain any non-whitespace characters, keep asking
    while guess.strip() == '':
        guess = input('Guess the capital of the state chosen : ')

    # if the cleaned up, case-insensitive guess matches the answer, you win
    if guess.strip().lower() == answer.lower():
        print("Yay! You're CORRECT!")

    # otherwise, you lose
    else:
        print("Sorry, You're INCORRECT!")

main()
```